# Can one enable or disable a mailbox with the EWS Managed API?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

One can create, enable and disable a mailbox using Powershell commands. Is it possible to do the same using the EWS Managed API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, EWS is just a web service it has nothing to do with mailbox creation.

Here you can find all operations supported by EWS.
[Exchange server 2007]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb409286%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

[Exchange server 2010]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb409286%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

[Exchange server 2013]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb409286%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

You can write c# application for Create,enable,disable mailbox using powershell

Comment: You welcome, i had done some work on exchange server if you have any question feel free to ask.